# Calculating Median - Report Builder 3 - SSRS - "Median=0" - What is wrong with my code?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report, median, ssrs-expression

These are my datasets:

[image: These are my data sets]

Average Cost column and expression

[image: Average Cost column and expression]

This is my Median column and expression

[image: This is my Median column and expression]

Details Group Property variables and expression

[image: Details Group Property variables and expression]

Code that I am using to TRY and calculate the median

[image: Code that I am using to TRY and calculate the median]

These are the results.

[image: These are the results]

The Median is always zero and I would really like to know why. If any further information is needed to try and resolve this please leave a comment and I will do it ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you returned the median in the **AddValue** function?

```
Function AddValue(newValue As Decimal)
    If values Is Nothing Then
        values = New System.Collections.ArrayList
    End If

    values.Add(newValue)

    Return GetMedian()
End Function
```

You could then use **AddValue** as the expression for the **Median** column:

```
="Median = " & Code.AddValue(Fields!AvgCost.Value)
```

Comment: You see, depending on the parameters, I receive all of the same values on each row. They are never different. I just noticed this. So where if the parameter is set to a week ago, "Median = 0" and if the parameter is set to a year ago, "Median = $500" for every row.

Comment: When I was testing this earlier, the function returned the median of the current list for every row. Depending on the values, the median differed for each row. You can try my code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9pUBX7).

Comment: Hi tino, thank you for your time. two questions! 1. On the link to your code, the "Console.WriteLine(code.AddValue(10))" is displayed as having a median of "9.5". How does that work? And also, to implement this code into my code, how would I call my AvgPrice values? Just like how you used the Console.WriteLine to call your values, but with fields!

Comment: That's just example code for testing. Don't mind the `Console.WriteLine` stuff, I only use it to call `AddValue`, which, on its turn, will return `GetMedian` for the current list. `Console.WriteLine` will then print the returned value in a "console window". I don't think `Console.WriteLine` even exists in SSRS. You only need the 2 functions.

Comment: I know! :) I removed all that stuff and the End Class stuff aswell! It runs now, but I don't know if it is running correctly. I am creating a thread now and if I may, post the link here for you to look at VERY quickly? Please!

Comment: The median is the middle value in a sorted list. As your list contains at least 11 zero's, it's possible for the median to be 0. It doesn't matter how large the numbers are.

Comment: Would you recommend writing a query for a percentile function? as opposed to this way? Because I think that's what I am going to do.

Comment: It's not clear from your original question what your full intentions are. The problem you had showing the median should have been solved by the answer I provided. I can't help you with issues with your logic.